# как сссылку без https сделать внешней

Tags: javascript, html

есть ссылка с якорем somesite.com как такую ссылку в теге а сделать чтобы переходило не внутрь сайта а во внешний сайт

```
<a href="somesite.com">site</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="//somesite.com">site</a>
```

Только в таком случае при переходе сохранится протокол твоего сайта.